# How to set the default geom_text color in R ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making many plots and want to set a default color for the data labels without having to pass the `color` argument to every `geom_text` call. I can do it for the plot titles and axes, but not the data labels.

```
# Example of how to set default color for other text elements
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw() + theme(text = element_text(color = "red"),
                             axis.text = element_text(color = "red")))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, label = ..count..)) +
    geom_bar() +
    geom_text(stat = "count") +
    labs(title = "title")
```

Comment: One possible solution, found at http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/update_defaults.html. `update_geom_defaults("text", list(colour = "red")); ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_text(label=hp)`

Comment: @bdemarest post as answer?

Comment: @bdemarest This is the solution I'm looking for. You should post as answer

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I believe theme elements are only intended to apply to non-data-related elements of the plot, meaning the theme does not cover the text in `geom_text`. The default color `"black"` is hard-coded in the source of `geom_text`, so as far as I know, there's not a simple way to override it. (Though, if someone cares to correct me, excellent!)

However, one simple solution that may help streamline things is to create a wrapper function that will return a `geom_text` with all the defaults that you will be passing over and over. For example:

```
geom_text_wrap <- function(col="red", ...) {
  geom_text(col=col, ...)
}
```

can be used in place of `geom_text` directly, and will, by default, create red text. So the following will create red text without you having to specify it directly in the plot creation.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, label = ..count..)) +
    geom_bar() +
    geom_text_wrap(stat="count") +
    labs(title = "title")
```

**Note:** If you really are creating a ton of similar plots to the point that you are tiring of specifying repetitive arguments, you may consider writing a function that will create the complete graph objects programmatically. That will depend on your specific use-case.